# Pyqt passing parameters to a form based on user action

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a form and a popup form as given below (partial code):

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_auto import Ui_Form
from popup_ui import Ui_Form as fm

class MyPopupForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = fm()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
    def when_pressed(self):
         self.mypopup=MyPopupForm()
         self.mypopup.show()
    def when_stopped(self):
         self.mypopup=MyPopupForm()
         self.mypopup.show()
```

Myform is my main form and MyPopupForm is the popup form. I need to do in such a way that, when I press a button it will print some string and display that string. When I press another button i have to invoke the same form but with different string. How could I do that (I used Qtdesigner to create UI)

MyPopupForm code in python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'popup.ui'
#
# Created: Sun Jan  8 11:18:43 2012
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.7.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(207, 170)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 120, 92, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(58, 30, 81, 41))
        #self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), Form.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "OK", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a parameter to the `__init__` method of the class MyPopupForm

`def __init__(self, string_to_be_passed=None, parent=None):`

and then when you call it with

`self.mypopup=MyPopupForm("value_to_display")`

using the string_to_be_passed in the `__init__` method to display the value.

Another method is to add a method to the class MyPopupForm to set the string to display and then

```
self.mypopup=MyPopupForm()
self.mypopup.setValueToDisplay("value")
self.mypopup.show()
```

with the `setValueToDisplay()` that display the string where needed.

Comment: I use qt designer to design forms. I gave `self.ui.setText(val)` after `self.ui = fm()`. It is now giving me the error `AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'setText'`

Comment: You should use `self.ui.<control>.setText(val)` where `<control>` is the QLabel or the QLineEdit or whatever control you use to show the text (which of couse must have the `setText()` method. The code you write, following your code example, is trying to call the method `setText()` fo the `MyPopupForm`, which beeing a QWidget does not have the method.

Comment: Sorry for the dump question. I am just a beginner. I gave `self.ui.QLabel.setText(val)` in mypopupform class and gettig the error `AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'QLabel'
`

Comment: QLabel is the name of the class, not the name of the widget. Is you use Qt Designer, check the name of the QLabel in the properties window the property `objectName`  of the widget. If you don't change the name, it is probably `label`

Comment: I use QtDesigner and the name is label. So when I call like this `self.ui.label.setText(val)`, I get the error `AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'label'. popup form pythoc code is given in the question.
`

Comment: There is a thing I don't understand: you are calling Ui_Form() in the `__init__` method of the class `MyForm` and also in the `__init__` method of the class `MyPopUpForm`. Why this ?  Also note that, given how you import the modules, it seems that `Ui_Form` is referring to a class/object imported from the ui_auto file given the line `from ui_auto import Ui_Form` and that if you import the popup with the line `from popup_ui import Ui_Form as fm` you must refer to it as `fm` and not `Ui_Form`. Anyway, can you post a minimal working example ?

Answer (score 2):

When compiling the python module with `pyuic4`, I think it is best to use the `-w` option, which will create a much simpler ui class without all the `setupUi` nonsense.

Doing it that way also means the class has exactly the name you gave it in Designer (rather than the nasty mangled version with the `Ui_` prefix), and it's also much simpler to subclass it if you need to.

Below, I've included a `ui` file with a simple `Dialog` class for showing a message. There's also a script that demonstrates how to use it.

Save the `ui` file as `dialog.ui`, and do:

```
pyuic4 -w dialog.ui > dialog.py
```

to compile the python module. Then run the script from the same directory.

**UI File**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>125</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="labelMessage">
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="buttonClose">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Close</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonClose</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>194</x>
     <y>107</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>402</x>
     <y>88</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

**Script**:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from dialog import Dialog

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.buttonOne = QtGui.QPushButton('Test One', self)
        self.buttonOne.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonOne)
        self.buttonTwo = QtGui.QPushButton('Test Two', self)
        self.buttonTwo.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonTwo)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonOne)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonTwo)

    def showDialog(self, message):
        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.labelMessage.setText(message)
        dialog.show()

    def handleButtonOne(self):
        self.showDialog('This is the message for Button One')

    def handleButtonTwo(self):
        self.showDialog('This is the message for Button Two')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```